# Prove that there exists a number $ x_{0} \in (0,1) $ such that $ f''(x_{0})=0 $

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $ f $ be a function continuous on $ [0,1] $ and twice differentiable on $ (0,1) $ . Suppose that

> $$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x) dx = f(0)=f(1) $$

Prove that there exists a number $ x_{0} \in (0,1) $ such that $ f''(x_{0})=0 $

Comment: As a hint, you may treat the integral as a function. That is $F(x) = \int^x_0 f(x)dx$. Then the Mean Value Theorem and Rolle's Theorem allows you to deduce that there are certain points within $(0, 1)$ with certain properties.

Comment: I might have a gist of what you've said. Please take a look at my working:
Define $F(x) = \int\limits_0^x {f(x)dx} $, then $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=f(1)$. By MVT, there exists $c \in (0,1)$ s.t. $F'(c)=f(c)=f(1)=f(0)$. By Rolle's Theorem, there exists $x_{1} \in (0,c)$ and $x_{2} \in (c,1)$ s.t. $f'(x_{1})=f'(x_{2})$. Another application of Rolle's Theorem gives $x_{0} \in (x_{1},x_{2}) s.t. f''(x_{0})=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(x)\ dx
$$
By Integral Mean Value Theorem,
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ dx =f(x_1)\int_{0}^{1}dx=f(x_1) \hspace{1 in} (for\ x_1\in(0,1))
$$
This should gives you a great hint in relating F(x) to f(x).

Remarks:
The Full Version of Integral Mean Value Theorem is:
$$
Suppose\  f(x)\ and \ g(x)\ are\  real\ valued\ function\ defined \ on\ [a,b]\ such\ that \ f(x)\ is\ continuous\ and \ g(x)\geqslant 0\ for \ every \ x \in[a,b].\\Hence \ there\ is \ a \ number\ x_1 \in[a,b]\ such\ that\\
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)\ dx=f(x_1)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\ dx \hspace{1in} (for\ x_1\in(a,b))
$$